# Inner Error: Message: controllerFactory.createForCurrentScope is not a function

Tags: validation, typescript, aurelia

I am recieving the above error in the aurelia view model

> Inner Error: Message: controllerFactory.createForCurrentScope is not a
>   function

Here is the code,

```
export class UpdateClient {
    public httpClient: HttpClient;
    public router: Router;
    public clientHelper: ClientHelper;
    public validator: Validator;
    public canSave: boolean;
    public controller: ValidationController;    
    public client: Client ;

 constructor(httpClient: HttpClient, router: Router, clientValidator: ClientValidator, clientHelper: ClientHelper, controllerFactory: ValidationControllerFactory, validator: Validator) {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
        this.clientHelper = clientHelper;
        this.router = router;
        this.client = new Client
        this.controller = controllerFactory.createForCurrentScope(validator);
        clientValidator.validate(this.client, clientHelper);
}
```

Comment: did you update any dependencies recently?
are you using npm for that pupose?
if both answers are yes - then remove package.lock.json
and npm i

Comment: there is also some info missing on the language/bundler/loader
I assume TS but there is no @autoinject seen on your class..

Comment: no  it works if i remove clientvalidator.validate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `@autoinject()` or any other decorator on your `UpdateClient` class for the type metadata to be emitted correctly.

`ValidationControllerFactory` is registered with DI as a resolver in the module file, so simply importing that (which you have, otherwise you'd get a type error) should give you the correct thing.

You may need to double check that you have `experimentalDecorators` and `emitDecoratorMetadata` set to true in your `tsconfig.json`.

Also make sure you are registering the validation plugin in your `main.ts` like so:

`aurelia.use.plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-validation'))`